# HTML - Add icon to browser tab

Tags: html, css, icons

I'm doing an assignment for class, and we were tasked to make a webpage. All went well with creating the page, but I'm struggling to get the icon on my browser tab.

He instructed us to get the icon from one of our folders

This is from his directions

"Note in order to show your icon, you insert this line in your html head section"

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="favicon/ico" />
```

"Assuming that your company icon is in the folder images"

I've tried many variations of that, but it won't work.

Mine is called favicon(1).ico

Here's one of my attempts

```
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon(1).ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Here's another.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon(1).ico" type="favicon/ico" />
```

I have a folder on my Desktop called "Question 1" and within that folder I have my HTML file for this assignent and another folder called "images". In the "images" file I have the "favicon(1).ico icon.

Is there a way I can take that icon from my folder and place it in my code?

Comment: Try inserting the entire image url path.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the Snippet that I use whenever I need to configure a favicon:

```
<!-- for FF, Chrome, Opera -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">

<!-- for IE -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/favicons/favicon.ico" >
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/favicons/favicon.ico"/>
```

This should work just fine.

You need to use .png in FF, Chrome and Opera and support them with 2 resolutions, for different devices and screen resolutions.

IE needs the .ico Image and needs the rel to be "icon" and "shortcus icon", don't ask me why, IE is always a bit of a wierdo as we all know :D

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon(1).ico">
```

or this (for Mozilla)

```
<link href="favicon(1).png" rel="icon" type="image/png" />
```

It can be .png or .ico

Comment: Try it. I have never used .ico, so maybe that is it.

Comment: Well, I was able to get it to work by putting the favicon.ico in the same folder as my HTML file, but the icon is next to the URL, not in the top left corner of the browser tab.  Do you know how to get it to the top left corner of the browser tab?

Comment: Well... I don't know what browser are you using, but I believe it is problem on the side of the browser, not in the code. Try to google "favicon not showing in <name of your browser> tab" and you should be fine ;)